# can I upgrade from 6.1 to 7?

Tags: system-installation

It is so bothersome to reinstall everything.
Is it so difficult to provide the chance
to simply upgrade from 6.1 to 7
without erasing the disk?
As elementary OS is based on Ubuntu,
there must be a way...

Comment: It is ridiculous, and they are literally shooting themselves on the foot... At this point in time i would never think this was the case... Oh Well.. time to say goodbye for good.

Comment: Well, and THAT is why I only use Linux distributions that are rolling releases.
There’s literally no point in any other release format in a day and age when 90% or more all software is distributed as online downloads. Fixed releases are from a time when you had to ship out CDs/DVDs to people…

Comment: Its a shame. Its a wonderful and beautiful end user OS, but until they figure it out how to allow to update from the last major release to the next, it will never make it to the big leagues.

Comment: It's possible to upgrade by editing /etc/apt/sources.list manually and running apt-get dist-upgrade. I had success via this method during upgrade from 5 to 6. But this is not a very safe approach.

Answer (score 1):

The [release upgrade guide](https://github.com/elementary/os/wiki/Release-Upgrades#performing-a-release-upgrade) suggests this is not possible currently, so you cannot do an in-place upgrade from 6 to 7, for this release upgrade:

> a fresh install is currently the only officially-supported way to upgrade

https://github.com/elementary/os/wiki/Release-Upgrades#performing-a-release-upgrade

Comment: and that's why I will not bother moving from 6.1 to 7.0